# How to map [...Array()] list in Nextjs

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I been doing a tutorial and have been caught up in a headache bug for 3 days.

My values aren't being iterated:

```
<Select value={item.quantity} onChange={(e) =>updateCartHandler(item, e.target.value)}>
    {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((num) => (<MenuItem key={num + 1} value={num + 1}>{num + 1}</MenuItem>))}</Select>
```

It only outputs : 1.

Should give a list from 1...20

Comment: Delete the value={item.quantity} from select component.

Comment: @PaimanRasoli didn't work, but thanks

Comment: What's the value of `item.countInStock`? Whatever you have in there, `Array(item.countInStock)` is returning an array with a single entry.